# Getting error 415 (Unsupported Media Type) while posting data using $http.post() in AngularJs and Spring

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

Hi I created one Spring with angularjs application. I am trying post some data and get the response. It is always displaying **415 (Unsupported Media Type)** error. How to fix it.

**index.jsp**

```
<html data-ng-app="myModule">
<head>
<title>AngularJS POST Spring MVC</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

    myModule.controller("MyController", function($scope, $http) {
            var dataObj = {
                name : "Ranga",
                location : "India",
                phone : "9986183"
            };


        $http.post('hello', dataObj).then(function(data){
            $scope.responseData = data;
        }, function(data){
            alert("Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
        });     

    });

</script>
</head>
    <body ng-controller="MyController">     
        <div>
            <p>Response:  {{responseData}}</p>      
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.ranga.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String hello(@RequestBody Person person) { 
        System.out.println("Hello, Person info is: "+person);

        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        data.append("Name: "+person.getName()+" ");
        data.append("Location: "+person.getLocation()+" ");
        data.append("Phone: "+person.getPhone());       
        return data.toString();
    }

}
```

**Person.java**

```
package com.ranga.controller;

public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String location;
    private String phone;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ranga.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ranga</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMVCAngularJS</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringMVCAngularJS Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>SpringMVCAngularJSService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

</build>
</project>
```

Comment: There's no need to set the headers in your Angular code. It's not necessary to build a String in your Spring controller. You can directly return the `Person` instance. And you should include Jackson 2.x. Have you checked what `Content-Type` header is actually sent to the server?

Answer (score 0):

As coded, your controller knows it has to expect JSON but when you are making ajax call, you need to add to your header that you are actually posting JSON.
Use this while making AJAX call.

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: Hi i am already added Content-Type in headers.                                                      var response = $http({
                   method: 'POST',
                   url: 'hello',
                   data: dataObj,
                   headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
             }});

Comment: Sorry, missed that. We have had a similar problem which this had fixed.

I think you also need manually Stringify the JSON. 

JSON.stringify(data)

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify the data before send it, in your controller you can do somethig like:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.controller("MyController", function($scope, $http) {
        var dataObj = {
            name : "Ranga",
            location : "India",
            phone : "9986183"
        }; 

       jsonDataObj = JSON.stringify(dataObj);     

        var response = $http({
               method: 'POST',
               url: 'hello',
               data: jsonDataObj,
               headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
         }}); 

        response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.responseData = data;
        });
        response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
        });

});
```

Also you can do it in a more "Angular way", changing your AJAX call to:

```
$http.post('hello', jsonDataObj).then(function(data){
    $scope.responseData = data;
}, function(data){
    alert("Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved the problem. I added the following dependencies in the pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```